# How to distinguish capture image photo album selected image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

how to distinguish between capture image and photo album Image

After capture Image its show Retake or UsePhoto,  On UsePhoto i am saving image to photo library and set to imageView.

On Click Upload From album, selected image set to **UIImageView**

But for both case the delegate method will call. Image upload from photo library or Image capture from the camera roll.

Do not want to save image when selected photo library.

and save image when select the camera capture and "Use Photo".

```
imageview.image = image;

-(void)imageUploaded:(NSInteger)selectedIndex{
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if (selectedIndex == 0){
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else if (selectedIndex == 1){

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else if (selectedIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Zero Index ");
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{

    if(image != nil){
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
     imageview.image = image;
    }
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

> picker.sourceType

to detect if the image was taken using the camera or if it was selected from camera roll.